# Flink: Why source of Reduce, Fold, Aggregations is KeyedStream instead of DataStream?

Tags: functional-programming, apache-flink, reduce, fold, flink-streaming

According to the documentation of Apache Flink: [DataStream Transformations](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/datastream_api.html#datastream-transformations).

All of Reduce, Fold, Aggregations are representing the transformation **from `KeyedStream` to `DataStream`** instead of **from `DataStream` to `DataStream`**.

I would like to know why?

As far as I understand, you can still do `reduce` or `fold` or `min`/`max` (aggregations) on a (non-keyed) DataStream, like `map` or `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we want to do some aggregation based on some `keys`. For example, assuming input for streaming is a Tuple2(groupId: String, userId: String). With the KeyedStream using `groupId` as a key, the API provides convenient way to count number of users for each group.

Of course, if we just want to get the global min userId for all input data, we could simply use map on DataStream to achieve that.